# How do I find out the internal ip address of a router in front of a firewall

Tags: firewall, ip, router

We have a network with a firewall and outside of the firewall the router to connect to the isp.
How do I find out what the internal ip is of that router. I do know the external ip, our fixed ip, but I can't connect to the router that way.
I checked the manual, and the firewall is using the ip that is the default internal ip for this type of router.

The only thing in the routing table of the firewall is:

```
interface  ip address  netmask  gateway      metric  options  
outside    0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0  192.168.1.1  1       none
```

Where 192.168.1.1 is the address of the firewall itself.

Comment: Have a look at the route table in the firewall?

Comment: The only thing in the route table is:

Comment: Try and add it to the question..

Comment: Run a tracert from your computer to www.google.com (or whatever) and look at the next hop address beyond your firewall address.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the routing table of a computer on the network.  On linux that's:

```
netstat -rn
```

On windows get a command prompt and run:

```
route print
```

You probably don't need to know the whole of the format of that output to spot the router's IP on the same line as your local network address range.